# Method in options object initialization is only called once per page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code

```
$(".datePicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    autoSize: true,
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    yearRange: getYearRange()
});
```

The getYearRange function is only called once although there are many .datePickers.
To be clear, the getYearRange function will be called with the $(this) parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the function name **without** the "()". When you do that, you'll be setting that configuration property to a reference to the function. When you code it with "()", you're telling JavaScript to **call** the function while it's putting together that object so that it can use the return value.

Now, that assumes that the date picker code **expects** a function there.  If what you want to do is initialize each of your date picker widgets with some special computed year range, based on characteristics of the DOM element(s) involved, then you'd do something different:

```
$('.datepicker').each(function() {
  var $dp = $(this);
  $dp.datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    autoSize: true,
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    yearRange: getYearRange.call(this)
  });
});
```

That would make sure that each date picker has a chance to figure out its own year range individually.

*edit* — reviewing the jQuery UI datepicker documentation, I don't think it'll invoke your "getYearRange" function if you pass it that way (as a function reference).  Thus, if you want the function to run once for *each* date picker on the page, then you'd use the ".each()" loop above.

Comment: Well did you do the first thing I wrote, or the second thing?  I'll check the jQuery UI docs.  It all depends on what your "getYearRange" function does, but you didn't post it so I don't know exactly what your goal is.

Comment: my reply was on the first answer. I'll give the second one a shot. Looks solid on first sight. Wish my JS was beter ;)

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. What is exactly the difference between myFunction, myFunctio() and myFunction.call ?

Comment: I used "getYearRange.call(this)" because you suggested (I think) that the function should be called with `this` referring to the date picker element being initialized.  If you just called "getYearRange()" like that, then `this` would not be set correctly. (Of course, you could just alter the function so that you could pass "this" as a simple parameter, so you'd say "getYearRange(this)" instead.  Either approach would work.